# Retrofit - Android - Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I am trying to parse following JSON data using Retrofit
`{
  "message": false,
  "suggestions": false,
  "vehicle": {
    "parked": true,
    "uin": "15",
    "vin": "WBAEG1312MCB42267",
    "make": "Bmw",
    "model": "E8SERIES",
    "color": "Blue",
    "year": "1991",
    "package": "Premium",
    "options": "",
    "interior": "Color: Cream, Type:Leather",
    "exterior": "",
    "activity": "Parked",
    "username": "Dhruba Sarma",
    "timestamp": "04-Sep, 00:35",
    "latlng": {
      "lat": 12.899270164792,
      "lng": 77.646080134509
    }
  }
}`

I have created my model classes as follows -
VehicleModel.java

`public class VehicleModel {

```
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private Boolean message;
@SerializedName("suggestions")
@Expose
private Boolean suggestions;
@SerializedName("vehicle")
@Expose
private Vehicle vehicle;

public Boolean getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public Boolean getSuggestions() {
    return suggestions;
}

public Vehicle getVehicle() {
    return vehicle;
}
```

Vehicle.java
`public class Vehicle {

```
@SerializedName("parked")
@Expose
private Boolean parked;
@SerializedName("uin")
@Expose
private String uin;
@SerializedName("vin")
@Expose
private String vin;
@SerializedName("make")
@Expose
private String make;
@SerializedName("model")
@Expose
private String model;
@SerializedName("color")
@Expose
private String color;
@SerializedName("year")
@Expose
private String year;
@SerializedName("package")
@Expose
private String _package;
@SerializedName("options")
@Expose
private String options;
@SerializedName("interior")
@Expose
private String interior;
@SerializedName("exterior")
@Expose
private String exterior;
@SerializedName("activity")
@Expose
private String activity;
@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;
@SerializedName("timestamp")
@Expose
private String timestamp;
@SerializedName("latlng")
@Expose
private LatLng latlng;



public Boolean getParked() {
    return parked;
}

public String getUin() {
    return uin;
}

public String getVin() {
    return vin;
}

public String getMake() {
    return make;
}

public String getModel() {
    return model;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public String getYear() {
    return year;
}

public String getPackage() {
    return _package;
}

public String getOptions() {
    return options;
}

public String getInterior() {
    return interior;
}

public String getExterior() {
    return exterior;
}

public String getActivity() {
    return activity;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public LatLng getLatlng() {
    return latlng;
}
```

}`

And finally LatLng.java
`public class LatLng {

```
@SerializedName("lat")
@Expose
private Double lat;
@SerializedName("lng")
@Expose
private Double lng;

public Double getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public Double getLng() {
    return lng;
}
```

I even tried using jsonschema2pojo for reference. But i still get the below error
**com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT**

Please suggest what am i doing wrong ?

EDIT- Here is how i am parsing JSON

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

    VehicleRequestInterface request = retrofit.create(VehicleRequestInterface.class);
    Call<VehicleJSONResponse> call = request.getVehicleJSON(url);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<VehicleJSONResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<VehicleJSONResponse> call, Response<VehicleJSONResponse> response) {

            VehicleJSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
            vehicleData = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getVehicle()));
```

Comment: According to your error message, you're trying to parse an object as an array.  You haven't actually shown us the code where you try to parse the json, so it's hard to know what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @azurefrog Please check, i have updated the question.

Comment: Show the declaration of vehicleData . How did you declare that ?

Comment: @shuvro `private ArrayList<VehicleModel> vehicleData;`

Comment: You have no arrays in your json. That's your problem here.

Comment: @MuratK. could u please suggest a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your `vehicleData` variable  like this  .

```
ArrayList<VehicleModel> vehicleData = new ArrayList<VehicleModel>();
```

And then in onResponse  rather than

```
vehicleData = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getVehicle()));
```

add like this way

```
vehicleData.add(jsonResponse.getVehicle())
```

The problem is you have no arrays in your json

Comment: now i am getting NullPointerException when i try to retrieve the data. `vehicleData.get(0).getVehicle().getLatlng().getLat();`

Comment: Can you read the other value like vehicleData.get(0).getVehicle().getMake() ;

Comment: Nope. I tried it, but same result. I have also checked that `vehicleData` is not null. Not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: `vehicleData.get(0).getVehicle()` is null. Not sure why !! Could u help

Comment: debug  vehicleData , lets check if u get something

Comment: i am getting `vehicleData={VehicleModel@6641}` `message=false` `suggestions=false` `vehicle=null`  What next ??

Comment: try calling your api in postman , just check your api response correctly

Comment: i have already checked it on postman. The response is as expected. For your reference VehicleJSONResponse.jave looks like this `public class VehicleJSONResponse {

    private VehicleModel vehicle;

    public VehicleModel getVehicleJSONResponse() {
        return vehicle;
    }
}`  FYI i am now retrieving the data like this `vehicleData.getVehicle().getColor()`